# Get data from MySQL database and add to list (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So using a list of ids, I'm trying to get data for each element in the database and add that element to a list. At the end, I'm displaying it on an HTML page. How would I do that? Right now, since it executes the queries async, the list will be empty after running the code to execute the query and add the result to a list.

Comment: Promise.all is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you give us a better sense of what your code looks like including any frameworks you are using and how you're interfacing with your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have a table called `teams` that contains a row for each team, with columns like `id`, `games`, `total_points`, `wins`, and `losses`.

Lets assume you have an array of team `id`. You want to query the database for those records, then do some things with them before returning them to the front end as json.

This is how i understand your problem. If this isn't the case, please clarify in a comment on this answer.

Possible solution:
Do it all in one query. I'm going to use my favorite mysql library, [knexjs](http://knexjs.org/).

```
var columns = ['id', 'games', 'total_points', 'wins', 'loses'];

function getTeams(ids){
  return knex.select(columns).where('id', 'in', ids)
    .then((teams) => {
      //do whatever with array of teams
      return teams;
    }
}
```

It's pretty much as simple as that.

Comment: I actually ended up doing that when I figured out I could do more then one WHERE statement. Thanks!